# Measure correlation without counting some values

Tags: python, numpy, correlation

I have an array:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [0,0,3], [1,2,0],[0,2,3]])
```

which looks like:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [0, 0, 3],
       [1, 2, 0],
       [0, 2, 3]])
```

I need to calculate paired correlations, **but without** taking `0`s in considerations. So, for example correlations between "1" and "2" should be calculated between arrays:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2]])
```

**Problem:** Numpy and pandas method will consider zeros and i can't remind them. 
So, **I need** a faster, willingly built-n method for this.

Though, i wrote mine algorithm, but it works really slow on large arrays.

```
correlations = np.zeros((1000,1000))
for i, column_i in enumerate(np.transpose(array_data)):
    for j, column_j in enumerate(np.transpose(array_data[:,i+1:])):
        if i != j:
            column_i = np.reshape(column_i,(column_i.shape[0], 1))
            column_j = np.reshape(column_j,(column_j.shape[0], 1))
            values = np.concatenate([column_i, column_j],axis=1)
            values = [row for row in values if (row[0] != 0) & (row[1] != 0)]
            values = np.array(values)
            correlation = np.corrcoef(values[:,0], values[:,1])[0][1]
            correlations[i,j] = correlation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, i decieded to change all zeros in data to `np.nan`

```
for i,e_i in enumerate(array_data):
    for j, e_j in enumerate(e_i):
        if e_j == 0:
            array_data[i,j] = np.NaN
```

and then, `pandas.corr()` worked fine...